# Can't view played game list from my dota profile

Tags: dota-2

When viewing my profile (or other's profiles) there's usually a button/link just above the commendations section that takes you to a list of all your games. I know longer have that button. Is that from a recent update or did I inadvertently change some settings to cause that ?

I also noticed that if I click 'View Heroes Played', that does take me to the performance list, but the filter no longer works. The filter shows you a list of games played by that hero.

Comment: Does this persist even when you restart the client?

Comment: Yes it does. Looks like a bug per WizLiz answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug that came up with the last update, there are [many complaints about this issue on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/search?q=recent%20game&sort=relevance&restrict_sr=on&t=day) and it should be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks WizLiz. And thanks to whoever up voted as I can't yet.